# Meteor Offline build ERROR

Tags: gradle, meteor, build, offline

Meteor Offline build ERROR!

> "compileSdkVersion is not specified" 
>      when no-internet connection I need to build at offline circumstance

error msg is like this.

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: compileSdkVersion is not specified.
.
.
.
.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/myFolder/Documents/workspace/myPjt/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build.gradle' line: 96

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:+.
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:+.
         > Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
            > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
                  > jcenter.bintray.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

but, if I connect internet again, it works again. 
Weird thing is that.. it works right after broke the connection and build. But maybe.. 24 hours later, it doesn't work once again till re-connect internet.

How is this possible?? Is there any time-out online check??
Please help...